# Rewritting QCQP as SOCP

Tags: optimization, qcqp, second-order-cone-programming

I have a convex function with convex constraints.
$$f(p) = \min_\limits{\| b_{0} - A_{0} x \|_{2} \le p} \| x \|_{2} = \min_\limits{\| b_{0} - A_{0} x \|_{2} = p} \| x \|_{2}$$
I was researching a lot about such problem, and found interesting  question right [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330896/can-a-convex-qcqp-with-an-additional-linear-constraint-be-converted-into-a-socp?rq=1). It loots like it is pretty simple to rewrite my task to SOCP in following format, if I am right.
$$\min \limits_{~~~~~~||x||_{2} \le y \\~~||A_{0}x - b_{2}||_{2} \le p} y $$
However I don't understand what is happening here. We are minimizing y, so it is taken from real numbers, but what are $x$ here then? Is it some fixed vector or what? It should not be, but what is it then. I don't get it completly.
Rewritting this problem as SOAP would allow me to use [this](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/socp.html)  method to compute that function.

Comment: Let me start from the end. If you want to use cvxpy then you don't need to reformulate anything or introduce auxiliary variables. cvxpy will do it for you. You just use cp.norm(b-A@x)<=p as constraints and cp.norm(x) as objective. The whole point of tools like cvxpy is that they perform the daunting task of squeezing your more abstract problem into the formal SOCP format.

Comment: But generally your reformulation is correct. $x$ means exactly the same thing in the second problem as it was in the first one, ie. probably a vector. $x$ is also an optimization variable. You ara using the fact that minimizing some function $h(x)$ is the same as minimizing $y$ subect to $y\geq h(x)$ (all other constraints the same)

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thank you for information about cp.norm. I was quite new to this tool, and it gave error when I tried to write somthing like x.T @ x. Said it doesn't allow DCP, that it why I wanted to rewrite that problem, but now it is no need to.

Comment: I also have 1 question about cvxpy then. I would like to know what algorithm it uses (I mean not specific that is implemented, just some general idea), in general words to read about it. Books I tried to read were quite strange (Boyd and else).  I just would like to understand that optimization method on paper. If you know something about it, that would be very nice.

Comment: cvxpy is not a solver. It models the problem, fits it into the correct format and sends it to underlying solver. In your case it will be a conic solver, so maybe SCS, ECOS, or one of commercial solvers .... etc. depending on what you have installed. See here  https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#choosing-a-solver For your problem type they mostly use some sort of interior-point algorithm. For other problem types/solvers it may be something else.

Comment: ok, Thank you.)